# Sort Records and Get Non Null Records at Top

Tags: mysql, sorting, record

I have a table "users" having data like

```
id   firstname  lastname
1    NULL       NULL
2    NULL       NULL
3    Tim        Kanter
4    John       Mathews
5    Brady      Allen
```

I need to get the records order by firstname but non null records should come first in ascending order. Therefore, How can i get the output like

```
id   firstname  lastname
5    Brady      Allen
4    John       Mathews
3    Tim        Kanter
1    NULL       NULL
2    NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN firstname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, firstname
```

Result:

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME
5   Brady       Allen
4   John        Mathews
3   Tim         Kanter
1   (null)      (null)
2   (null)      (null)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e8550/12).

Comment: I don't want to use UNION. in this case how we will get such output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `UNION`:

```
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstname IS NOT null
  ORDER BY firstname) AS `t1`
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstname IS  null
```

Comment: Error: `Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY: SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE firstname IS NOT null ORDER BY firstname UNION SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE firstname IS null`. See [**this fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e8550/4)

Comment: I don't want to use UNION. in this case how we will get such output?